# ¿Como definir el host y el puerto a usar en una app de Flask?

Tags: python, flask

Para ejecutar una aplicacion en Flask usamos el metodo

```
app.run()
```

En este metodo podemos pasar parametros de configuración, entre ellos:

```
host, port, debug
```

Por defecto la aplicación de Flask se ejecuta en

```
host = localhost
port = 5000
```

Por lo que, si deseamos cambiar esa configuracion, la pasamos al metodo run

```
app.run(host="10.100.100.10", port=9566)
```

En el caso de querer tener distintas configuraciones para tu aplicacion (ya sea, producción, desarrollo, pruebas) debes definir un diccionario de configuración, algo como esto:

```
app.config.update(
    DEBUG=True,
    SECRET_KEY='...'
)
```

Leyendo (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/) encontré este atributo:

```
SERVER_NAME
```

Citando la documentación de Flask:

> the name and port number of the server. Required for subdomain support
>   (e.g.: 'myapp.dev:5000') Note that localhost does not support
>   subdomains so setting this to “localhost” does not help. Setting a
>   SERVER_NAME also by default enables URL generation without a request
>   context but with an application context.

Este atributo deberia cambiar el host y el purto.

Defini entonces esto:

```
app.config.update(
    DEBUG=True,
    SERVER_NAME="10.100.100.10:6500"
)
```

Como resultado sigue mostrando al ejecutar la aplicacion

```
Running in 127.0.0.1:5000
```

**¿Como puedo hacer que mi aplicacion se ejecute en otro host y puerto sin tener que usar parametros dentro del metodo run?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La variable de configuración `SERVER_NAME` no es para indicarle a Flask que escuche en cierta IP y puerto, sino para indicarle que *está escuchando* en cierta IP y puerto.

Esa variable en general sólo es necesaria si la `app` está escuchando con un  nombre (o IP) diferente de la que ofrece públicamente (porque por delante tiene por ejemplo a `nginx` actuando como proxy, o se ejecuta en un contenedor, o porque está instalado en una máquina que, mediante hosting virtual, da servicio a varios servidores). En ese caso flask no puede saber cuál es su nombre:puerto públicos, y en cambio los necesita para poder resolver cuál es la url asociada (externamente) a una cierta ruta, para que `url_for()` pueda funcionar.

Que yo sepa, la única forma de cambiar la IP y puerto en que escucha, es pasarla como parámetro a `app.run()`. Ahora bien, en lugar de pasarle una IP y puertos "prefijados" desde el código fuente, perfectamente puedes hacer que los lea de un fichero externo, o de la propia configuración de la app.

Por ejemplo, el siguiente código toma el valor de configuración `SERVER_NAME` y extrae de él la IP y puerto, para pasárselas a `app.run()`:

```
server_name = app.config['SERVER_NAME']
if server_name and ':' in server_name:
    host, port = server_name.split(":")
    port = int(port)
else:
    port = 5000
    host = "localhost"
app.run(host=host, port=port)
```

El valor de esa variable de configuración estaría fijado en otra parte, por ejemplo con el código que tú mismo has puesto antes. Ese código típicamente no formaría parte de tu app, sino de un fichero de configuración. También podrías tomarlo de variables de entorno, que quizás fuera lo más adecuado.

Fíjate no obstante que, ya que la variable `SERVER_NAME` no está pensada para este cometido, el código anterior no es la mejor forma de hacerlo. Es posible que esa variable tenga un valor como: `https://mi.servidor.com` en cuyo caso el truco de partir por ":" para separar IP y puerto no funcionará. Es sólo un ejemplo de cómo puedes usar `app.config` para almacenar información que luego puedes usar dentro de la app. Si en vez de `SERVER_NAME` usas tu propia variable, mejor. Podríamos llamarla por ejemplo `IP_PUERTO`.

Investiga también el comando `flask`, que puedes usar en lugar de `python` para lanzar la aplicación (en ese caso la aplicación no contendrá un `app.run()` puesto que es el comando `flask` quien se encarga de invocarlo). A ese comando le puedes pasar por línea de comandos el host y puerto como parámetros (y él internamente se los pasa a `app.run()` cuando lo lanza).

### Actualización

Examinando el código fuente de flask, veo que `app.run()` efectivamente espera que le pases un nombre de host y si no lo pasas usará  `127.0.0.1`, y también espera que le pases un puerto, *pero si no lo pasas lo toma de `SERVER_NAME`* (y si allí no lo encuentra, usa 5000).

Este detalle no lo conocía y significa que en tu ejemplo, cuando pusiste en `SERVER_NAME` el valor "10.100.100.10:6500", la app debería estar escuchando en `127.0.0.1:6500` y no en `127.0.0.1:5000` como pusiste.

En todo caso, visto que la IP que estás poniendo es una IP privada, no creo que estés usando `SERVER_NAME` en la forma correcta. Debería contener la IP pública (o mejor el nombre DNS) a través de la cual se pueda acceder a tu app desde internet.